# Error trying to use stellar-sdk in the browser

Tags: javascript-sdk

I am trying to include stellar-sdk.js (for use on the browser side) like this:

```
import * as stellarModule  from './stellar-sdk.js';
```

The file stellar-sdk.js is present. However, I get this error, when trying to import it in the main js file:

```
stellar-sdk.js:14400 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (stellar-sdk.js:14400)
    at Object.exports.byteLength (stellar-sdk.js:16148)
    at __webpack_require__ (stellar-sdk.js:562)
    at Object.<anonymous> (stellar-sdk.js:41366)
    at __webpack_require__ (stellar-sdk.js:562)
    at Object.exports.default (stellar-sdk.js:28883)
    at __webpack_require__ (stellar-sdk.js:562)
    at Object.<anonymous> (stellar-sdk.js:28833)
    at __webpack_require__ (stellar-sdk.js:562)
    at Object.<anonymous> (stellar-sdk.js:26425)
    at __webpack_require__ (stellar-sdk.js:562)
    at Object.<anonymous> (stellar-sdk.js:26409)
    at __webpack_require__ (stellar-sdk.js:562)
    at Object._interopRequireWildcard (stellar-sdk.js:26367)
    at __webpack_require__ (stellar-sdk.js:562)
    at Object._interopRequireWildcard (stellar-sdk.js:26284)
```

Comment: What browser and SDK version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Stellar sdk browser side javascript is pulled from here: https://github.com/stellar/bower-js-stellar-sdk

Chrome browser Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) .

However, I got it to work for now by importing the stellar sdk javascript in the html file. I am not sure how I will package and ship my javascript module without solving importing stellar-sdk.js from another js file.
Ideally , I could refer to the stellar-sdk.js from my other js file, by importing it somehow, like this:

import * as stellarModule  from './stellar-sdk.js';

Comment: To clarify: when including in the html file like this: <script src="./public/javascriptstellar-sdk.js" ></script> it works fine. But I cannot include in another js file.